# Find average in datagridview

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

In column F in my DGV(DataGridView) in vb.net I have a list of 20 numbers.The numbers are usually figures like 23.56 or 22.67.I want to find the five highest of these numbers,average them out(the top five that is) and place the result in a textbox on the form.Any help much appreciated.
regards
al

Comment: so nobody knows then hmmmm!

Comment: Hmmm… Have you tried to sort column f, sum the top five, divide the result of the sum by 5 and place that value in the text box?